# Java JDK 20 fails on install windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, java

When I try to install jdk 20, it fails.
When I try to install with the MSI, it fails almost immediately with the message "installation failed.  The wizard was interrupted before Java(TM) Se development kit 20.0.1 (64-bit) could be completely installed....."
When I try with the "exe" version, it gives no message but just seems to quit on it's own.

I noticed that there is an old Java 8 Update 241 installed and I thought that could be the problem, so I tried uninstalling that. The uninstall failed because it could not find the .msi file for the uninstall. The Java program folder is in the program files (x86) folder indicating that this is a 32 bit installation. So based upon another thread here on superuser, I went to the java archive site and downloaded the jre-8u241-windows-i586.exe file which is the same release. The idea is to install it and then uninstall it to get rid of the old version. I tried to install but it failed because the install folder already existed. So then I renamed the install folder. Tried again and it stopped on error 1638 that indicates that there is already a version installed and it can't install over it. At some point in there it got through to the "remove old version" procedure which it went through and then announced the number of old versions removed was "0" and that the old versions remaining consisted of Java 8 Update 241. (sorry, can no longer remember the order in which that piece showed up.)

So then I tried the iobit uninstaller to uninstall the old version. It seemed to do a bunch of work and claimed to uninstall it and delete useless registry entries. Now the Java 8 Update 241 no longer shows up on the Progams and Features list.

Retried the 32 bit Java 8 Update 241 and it again crashed on error 1638.

Tried both ways of installing the JDK again and they still fail the same way.

I checked in the registry and there is, suspiciously, a reference to Java 8 update 241 in the Programs tree under the Install tree.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Thanks!

Comment: Never use the iobit uninstaller scamware. https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp and then the "Windows Offline (64-bit)" here: https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp Most people use https://openjdk.org/ nowadays; is that an option for you?

Comment: Java 8 and Java 20 can coexist on the same system. The reason the installation fails hasn’t anything to do with Java 8 being installed

Comment: Thanks Gantendo. I also tried the java uninstall tool. All that happens is it asks if I want to make changes, I answer yes, and then it quits. It doesn't have any effect on the problem.
I'm not sure if openjdk is an option. I want to run Android studio and all the documentation I see says I need to install the oracle jdk.

Comment: Thank-you Ramhound. I suspected that, but it was the only thing I could think of.